# Android: get only updated result from thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am developing socket based android application in which i need to get the status of button whether its ON or OFF. so what i want is i want only updated result from running thread means if status of any button gets changed then i should be notified to i can set button status accordingly.

here is my main class which checks for result every second.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("connected");
        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.1.19", 502);
            i = s.getInputStream();
            iD = new DataInputStream(i);
            o = s.getOutputStream();
            oD = new DataOutputStream(o);

            System.out.println("connected");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }, 0,1000);

    }
```

Here i have used `TimerTask` which runs on every second. but don't want to use timer task.

here is **ClientThread.java**

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    PollThread pollThread;
    String byte_to_hex,swapped_result,result;

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try 
        {
            byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
                { 
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, 
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x06, 
                    (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x19
                };

            PollThread.o.write(packet1);
            PollThread.i.read(data1, 0, 1024);

            /*Log.v("::::TX::::", ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(0, 26));
            Log.v("::::RX::::", ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(packet1));*/

            byte_to_hex = ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(18, 26);

            System.out.println(byte_to_hex);

            char[] arr = byte_to_hex.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) 
            {
                char temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            swapped_result=new String(arr);
            result = ConversionMethods.hexStringToNBitBinary(swapped_result, 32);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("In Catch Block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("In Catch Block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here i will get different result when status of any button will be changed. so i want this updated status value. so based on this i can perform some action.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly is your question? are the button and the code that wants to know the status of the button in the same app?

Comment: yeah,i want to update the button status based on result

Comment: You need to use a handler, intent, or create a new Runnable that updates the button and call the `myActivity.runOnUiThread(updateButtonRunnable)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the button to the thread when you are initializing it. And you can access the state from your thread.

```
 myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread(myButton));
                    cThread.start();
                }
    }, 0,1000);



public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    PollThread pollThread;
    String byte_to_hex,swapped_result,result;

public ClientThread(Button btn){
this.button = btn
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
```

....

Comment: can you give simple snippet of this implementation ?

Comment: i am getting null as a result, actually i have passed String instead of button because i want only result string.

Comment: pass a static object. or use a singleton